# How do I round this float decimal to two decimal places?

Tags: python, floating-point, decimal, rounding

I am new to python and am having some difficulties. How would I make this so that I can round the float(roll)*100 rounded to 2 decimal places.

```
for x in roll1:
        print('%d - %d %f%%' %(x,roll1[x], float(roll1[x])/float(roll)*100))
```

This is the output currently. I need to make the numbers rounded to 2 decimal places. Thanks!

```
1 - 1794 17.940000%
2 - 1620 16.200000%
3 - 1620 16.200000%
4 - 1611 16.110000%
5 - 1650 16.500000%
6 - 1705 17.050000%
```

Comment: @Kay, I would recommend indenting code blocks by 4 spaces and surrounding inline code with `. See [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `%.2f` instead of `%f` and `%`.

The `%f` format specifier has these options:

- A number not preceded by `.` specifies the maximum length of the output (number + `.` + decimals)
- A `.` followed by a number specifies the number of decimal places.
- Certain characters *immediately* after the `%` have special meanings:

  - (space) means that positive numbers should have a space prepended to them.
  - `+` means that positive numbers should have a `+` sign before them.